# Windows10端末でHTA（HTML Applications）で出現する「エラー8150002e」のダイアログを出現させないようにしたい。

Tags: javascript, html, windows-10, internet-explorer

端末ローカルに配置したHTA(HTML Applications)でWebシステムへ遷移するための画面を作成しています。
ただ、システムへの遷移ボタンで埋め込んだJavaScriptのsubmit処理が
実行されるタイミングで以下のようなエラーダイアログが発生します。

エラーダイアログの記載内容：

```
スクリプトエラー
※このページのスクリプトでエラーが発生しました。
ライン：　（発生した行数が表示）
文字：　（その行数内の何文字目かが表示）
エラー：　エラー8150002eのための操作を完了できませんでした。
コード：　0
URL：　（作成したHTAファイルの格納先が表示）

このページのスクリプトを実行し続けますか？
[はい]　[いいえ]
```

なお、IEのインターネットオプションには下記サイトを参考にした設定を施しています。

[Windows10でIEのスクリプトエラーが頻発・消えない時の対処法](https://itojisan.xyz/%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB/ie%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E9%A0%BB%E7%99%BA%E3%83%BB%E6%B6%88%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/)

※キャッシュなどを削除した後は出なくなることもありますが、恒久的に表示されなくしたいです。

何か有効な対応策（ソースの改善、端末設定の改善等）をご存知の方がいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 実行したのは IE のみですか？また IE だとしたら必須なのでしょうか？ / 参照したリンク先にもある通り、他のブラウザへの移行も一つの案として検討すべきかと思います。

Comment: @cubick 
システムの都合上IEは必須になります。。。
また、HTAファイルのボタン押下時の事象なのでIEを開く前段階でダイアログが出力されていると思います。

Comment: 問題のソースコードが提示されないことには「ソースの改善」は望めないと思います。